# Congratulations BalusC for reaching a million reputation!

Tags: discussion, reputation, users, top-users

Today (15 July 2021) a very well respected and brilliant member, [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc), has reached a million reputation points!

[image: profile for BalusC on Stack Overflow, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

As of today, he has posted 17,102 answers which we greatly appreciate.

Comment: Not to mention 15 questions :-)

Comment: I guess that would make him BalusMM :D

Comment: I think there should be new rank partition of 1,000,000+ with current 4 members within the Total Reputation part of stackexchange's league page along with a newly defined golden badge proper to them.

Comment: It happened only now? Jeepers the dude basically wrote the book on Javaserver Faces.

Comment: @Cerbrus No, MM is 2k. You probably meant M̄ (M with macron).

Comment: @iBug aw, Wikipedia lied to me :-(

Comment: 4-5 answers per day for every single day for almost 12 years, that's really mind blowing.

Comment: @BalusC was there to help me many years ago with JSF.  Congrats to you and continue with the good work.

Comment: @Cerbrus For 1m the M needs a line above it to state 'x1000'  ̅M (single M + horizontal line, called a vinculum on top)

Comment: @Coffeeholic: Yea, I was already told that...

Comment: I had a (rather brief) JavaEE phase, and in those days I ended up learning from dozens of his answers. Furthermore the man was immensely responsive and helpful on the comments. Legendary user and absolutely deserved million, glad to have contributed to that

Comment: @iBug: it is m, [lower case m](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87251/use-m-for-million-instead-of-m), on Stack Exchange. Apparently, Stack Exchange is US english, not international.

Comment: The fact that they have more silver badges than bronze badges is actually insane

Comment: [Check out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AG_3ONoWrug) how he got there! Thanks a ton @BalusC

Answer (score 139):

Welcome to the club, BalusC!

I have found out the only "privilege" that club bestows upon its member is to allow them to go on helping others and learning from them.

Comment: I think they should be handing out [Unicorn Paintings](https://149351115.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/jon-skeet-unicorn-painting.jpg) for members who achieve 1 million rep.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, rather a golden "Post your answer" button ;)

Comment: And the privilege to have the precision of your reputation reduced to one hundred thousand (10^5).

Comment: yeah i totally agree that Stackoverflow should award a privilege to the special users with over 1 million reputations :D

Comment: I think everyone (regardless of 1M rep) who can find 4 or more unique on-topic questions to answer in a single day should be lifted up in the air and publicly praised.  I am hard pressed to find more than 2 in a single session of volunteering.  49 out of 50 questions are either duplicates or otherwise justifiably closed.

Comment: you guys having your contribution to building this community stronger every second.

Answer (score 43):

Congratulations! I just wrote a song for this VERY SPECIAL OCCASION!! PARTY!! FUN TIMES!! YAHOOOOOOOOOOOOOPPPPOOOOOOOÚOÚOŐOŐ

https://vocaroo.com/1nmkkWeHoVm3

### Lyrics ([transcribed by Scratte](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte))

Num-num nun-na-na
Congrats
Congrats to BalusC
Oh Congrats
Congrats to BalusC
Oh Congrats
Congrats to BalusC
Oh Congrats
CONGRATS TO BALUSC!!!
Bubu-bam-ma-na-ma-na-ba-da-na-ma-ma-na-na-na na-na-ma-na-ma-na-mau
Da-da-da-da-da-dau

Comment: The cringe is real with this one...

Comment: Please note that this is [Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Comment: @Scratte no this is meta where we actually undo the butt-flap.

Comment: Aesthetically, I didn't find this to be worse than a unicorn painting, +1

Comment: welp, I have PTSD now.

Comment: Looking forward to see this on Spotify

Comment: Amazing. Wish I could sing like that :D

Comment: If this is satire then this is brilliant. If it's an honest attempt.... I'm extremely sorry.

Comment: To the brave people entering the link, I salute you.

Comment: It's no "Jeff Goldblum is watching you poop" (nsfw), but it's a commendable attempt. +1. Not mind infecting like [Tom's Diner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLP6QluMlrg), yet still surprisingly catchy.

Comment: Hah! Never saw something like this on Meta before. Have an upvote for your creativity :p

Comment: Upvoted for audacity, rather than artisic merit : )

Comment: Em has been real quiet since this dropped

Comment: I always thought no one could be cooler than Chris Prat riding alongside velociraptors... yep, chris prat still rocks, but well done Tamás-Sengel for doing something to recognise @BalusC

Comment: Yeah if I still hear this song in my head in 20 minutes my vengeance will be terrifying.

Comment: This is absolutely hilarious.

Comment: I can't "unhear" this! My ears need the auditory equivalent of bleach :/

Comment: I have never heard a better beat boxing song, my benchmarks have suddenly changed.

Comment: After having listened to this song around 47 times, I think I got the lyrics accurately down to:  Num-num nun-na-na congrats  Congrats to BalusC  Oh Congrats  Congrats to BalusC  Oh Congrats  Congrats to BalusC  Oh Congrats  CONGRATS to BALUSC  Bubu-bam-ma-na-ma-na-ba-da-na-ma-ma-na-na-na na-na-ma-na-ma-na-mau  Da-da-da-da-da-dau :)

Comment: Based. This is my ringtone now

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli hm, what would the equivalent of bleach be. White noise?

Comment: @Gimby Hahaha, that's what I first thought!

Comment: omg i totally didnt expect this, havent laughed this hard in a while

Comment: this is actually quite brilliant and neat :D

Comment: *[based](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/based#Adjective_2)* - *"2. (Internet slang, originally [4chan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4chan)) Praiseworthy and admirable, often through exhibiting independence and security. ... Antonyms: cringe, [unbased](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unbased#Adjective)"*

Answer (score 35):

My mentor for near everything of what I have learned about JSF and its related technologies. Congrats and I hope you can keep contributing for many more years! We the community really appreciate your work. As others have stated, here's my suggestion for 1M+ rep contributors:

[image: Golden "Post Your Answer"]

Comment: I tried `"linear-gradient(to bottom right, var(--white), var(--gold), var(--yellow-700), var(--yellow-900), var(--yellow-700), var(--gold-darker), var(--gold))"` but I can't get it quite right. What's your secret? :)

Comment: @Scratte try this in the button: `background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at right bottom, #FEDB37 0%, #FDB931 8%, #9f7928 30%, #8A6E2F 40%, transparent 80%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at left top, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFAC 8%, #D1B464 25%, #5d4a1f 62.5%, #5d4a1f 100%);` [Attribution](https://codepen.io/chilliconcode/pen/OWxqYR) ;-)

Comment: Yeah it was great having his knowledge (and tools) around when I was doing JSF. But I was far happier when I stopped using JSF :)

Comment: Neat!and surely some fancy badge or marker on their profile :D

Answer (score 17):

Last time I heard of BalusC on meta, was about a precautionary account-ban that resulted in quite a few emotions, and for a while it looked like BalusC would quit.

I am quite glad he didn't, and that we can now celebrate this.

Congratulations!

Answer (score 11):

I will never forget his help during my college days. I came across my first web server and had so many questions and doubts, was messing things up.

I asked a question on SO, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14120880/681929); childishly I was asking Balusc some out-of-routine questions under the answer posted by him and he kept replying to me in lengthy comments. Thanks Legend.

Answer (score 3):

Congrats @BalusC. The community is proud of you. Keep up the excellent work, and thank you from my heart.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations, BalusC. You deserve it.

The knowledge you've bestowed upon Stack Overflow helped a lot of budding developers (including me) starting out with Enterprise Java and web development. For that we owe you a lot.

Thanks, man!

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations **@BalusC**!!

Thanks for making this community stronger.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats, @BalusC. That is super.