# The Stack Overflow 1 Million Points Club!

Tags: discussion, reputation

One million points is a LOT of points on Stack Overflow. It represents a small handful of people, and it's a testament to those who have dedicated themselves to helping others. We do want to celebrate these accomplishments (because they often get no other recognition), but [we have had a problem with multiple overlapping Meta posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424359). This is the official place to recognize this achievement going forward (and, yes, we [got the idea from Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/congratulations-the-big-thread)). Any attempts to post separate congratulations in a different question will be duplicated to this post.

#### Instructions

When someone not on the list hits 1,000,000(1M) reputation

1. Post an answer for the new person who has hit 1M
2. Edit the list of people below. Please link to the Meta answer from Step 1.

> The original people had separate congratulatory Metas we've linked to. These people will not have a post here for that reason. **Do not create an answer for those people**.

Please note that this post will be locked at or above 50 people listed. Do not make any other congratulatory questions below 2,000,000 points.

| User | Date Added to List | Meta Post |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: profile for Jon Skeet on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites] | Jan 16, 2018 | [Thanks a million, Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362019) [Stack Overflow Blog for being first 1M](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/) |
| [image: profile for Gordon Linoff on Stack Overflow, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites] | Aug 20, 2020 | [Congratulations for reaching a million, Gordon Linoff!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400506) |
| [image: profile for VonC on Stack Overflow, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites] | Nov 29, 2020 | [Congratulations VonC for reaching a million reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403218) |
| [image: profile for BalusC on Stack Overflow, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites] | Jul 15, 2021 | [Congratulations BalusC for reaching a million reputation!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409154) |
| [image: profile for Darin Dimitrov on Stack Overflow, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites] | Aug 11, 2022 | [Congratulations Darin Dimitrov for reaching a million reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419768) |
| [image: profile for Martijn Pieters at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers] | Dec 7, 2022 | [Congratulations Martijn Pieters for reaching a million reputation!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421919) |
| [image: profile for Marc Gravell at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers] | Apr 28, 2023 | [Meta Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424425/the-stack-overflow-1-million-points-club/424426#424426) |
| [image] | Apr 28, 2023 | [Meta Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424425/the-stack-overflow-1-million-points-club/424430#424430) |

Comment: Would be interesting if, (at their time of reaching the 1M-Rep milestone), you could add a few Stats (not only about Rep but also their Curation activity) like: 'Date joined SO' / 'Member for x days' / 'Rep per day' / '#Gold/Silver/Bronze Badges' / 'Main 3 Tags' / '#Questions' / '#Answers' / '#Flags' / '#Closed Questions' / etc...

Comment: *this post will be locked at or above 50 people listed* - considering the current #50 has 'just' 550k rep, it might take a while until we get to this point...

Comment: How does one generate the flair for another user, manually?

Comment: @Bergi Copy their user URL from the main site. Then you'll modify this block `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/<userid>/<username>"><img src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/<userid>.png"></a>` Paste their URL into the `href` portion, then copy the userid (the number in the URL) and paste it into the `<img>` URL part. So your flair is `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi"><img src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1048572.png"></a>`

Comment: so how are we supposed to interpret [We are no longer allowing congratulatory posts on Meta for users reaching 1 million rep or less](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424359/11107541) based on this? Am I just confused or does that post seem to contradict with this one at its current revision (4)?

Comment: @user I freely admit that is confusing. [See my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424427/2370483)

Comment: Slightly off topic, is there any policy on congratulatory "questions" for other notable achievements on SO? For example: becoming a moderator, stepping down, handling flags, close vote reviews, etc. I don't have any strong views either way on congratulatory "questions" (though I definitely view 1 million rep as a far more significant achievement than becoming a moderator). But doesn't it make sense to have a consistent policy on all congratulatory "questions" on meta, regardless of the achievement?

Comment: @skomisa Probably worth a separate post for that. Staff does mod election postings, mod retirement posts are entirely done by the mod themselves (Tim Post, for instance, left with no fanfare by his own request). Review congrats are exceedingly rare ([100k reviews in a single queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407167) is almost as hard as 1M rep), but not encouraged. I'm not opposed to having the community craft better policy there.

Answer (score 39):

It is my pleasure to congratulate T.J. Crowder on this well-deserved achievement:

[image]

With over 15,000 [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) answers, he is the unrivaled top user for that tag, and he provides a constant stream<sup>1</sup> of high-quality posts with an astonishing acceptance rate of over 60%<sup>2</sup> and an average score of over 5.6 votes<sup>2</sup>.

Go on hunting for the next million! New questions keep piling in…

<sub>1: [big data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/90496/distribution-of-user-activity-per-hour#graph) says he has [a fixed sleeping schedule and dinner time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47KVO.png), very much [unlike me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xji5b.png) :-)

2: [more SQL statistics](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1747519/answer-statistics-of-top-users-in-tag?tag=javascript)</sub>

Answer (score 37):

[image: profile for Marc Gravell at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

Congrats to Marc Gravell on his 1M club achievement!

Marc isn't just a 1M point clubber, he's [also a former Stack Exchange employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370959/thank-you-marc-gravell). And he still helps folks on Stack Overflow. What a guy!